# Kies/ Smart Switch data transfer

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, samsung-galaxy-s-4, file-transfer, samsung-kies

How do we transfer data, music, or videos from S4 to the computer? Tried KIES but it says it's not compatible and to use smart switch instead. Installed smart switch, it says my device is not compatible.

Looked up FAQ for compatibility and found I must have  **Software: Android OS ICS (4.0) or higher**

Looked up my Android OS and found it to be 4.4.4 . Now I am unable to understand why is my S4 not compatible to use Smart switch. TIA.

Comment: Smart switch has had issues in some models. There are two versions of Kies. Try the latter one http://www.samsung.com/in/support/usefulsoftware/KIES/

Comment: I have tried both the versions.